# IOS: How to hide prompt area in NavigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I set prompt text for NavigationItem, and set a timer to remove it like below:

```
- (void)timerFire_HidePromote:(NSTimer*) theTimer
{
    [self.navigationItem setPrompt:@""];
}
```

The text can be removed, but the space of the prompt still here, how can I hide all prompt area?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this piece of code:

```
[self.navigationItem setPrompt:@""];
```

With this:

```
[self.navigationItem setPrompt:nil];
```